# Paralleling of battery chargers

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, buck, parallel, solar-charge-controller

Can we parallel the bbattery chargers suppose buck controllers.Two buck controllers taking power supply from the same power bus. The output of each controller will charge the batteries connected at the output terminals of the buck controller.
I will upload a schematic, is that possible?
Thanks and Regards[image: Parallel buck controllers]

Comment: You connect the outputs of a DCDC converter **in parallel**, don't do this. They're not designed for that. This will give issues as the currents from the DCDC converters will not be shared equally and also because it disrupts the voltage regulation of these modules.

Comment: Kranthi Kumar Banala - Hi, (a) This is currently an off-topic shopping question, as you are asking where to get evaluation boards for charge controllers & boost converters. So don't be surprised if the question is closed because of that. (b) The diagram doesn't match the text e.g. in text you say (i) 12V battery (diagram shows 3.7V); (ii) ORing circuits at boost converter o/p (diagram shows none); (iii) 36V battery charger i/p (diagram shows 5V) etc.; (iv) You added "microcontroller" tag (diagram shows none). Those are just examples of how this question could be clarified and improved. Thanks!

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie  I read that we can use ORing board so that we can connect the output of the converters to the same DC load bus. Even we can use current sharing evaluation board where we can give two dc dc converter inputs to the same board where it is having only 1 output terminal.

Comment: @SamGibson  I uploaded that figure just to get an idea. I even said that the voltages are different. I even asked whether this can be implemented or not. Asking some tips to implement this application.

Comment: @KranthiKumarBanala - Hi, "*I uploaded that figure just to get an idea*" IMHO it is confusing & unhelpful when the text and diagram in a question contradict each other, because then we don't know which one to believe! You could (and IMHO should) edit or replace that diagram, to match your *real* plan. "*Asking some tips to implement this application.*" To me, that request makes this a very broad question, and it still looks like a shopping question too - but I will leave it open for community voting and answers, at least for a while.

Comment: @KranthiKumarBanala - Hi, In [revision 3](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/551263/3) of this question, your edits have now completely changed the question. This revision of *this* question is now included as part of [your latest question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/552048/parallel-connection-of-dc-dc-converters-with-different-output-to-charge-the-batt), including the same diagram. Therefore I am closing *this* question as a duplicate of *that* question, as it wastes resources here to have multiple questions asking essentially the same question. Thanks.

Comment: thanks @SamGibson

Answer (score 1):

There is something called a "perfect diode" its an IC and a power MOSFET.  You can use it to or the outputs together and they will also provide some load balancing by either pick the best or adjusting their resistance to match the load.  I've used this in dual supplies up to 5A with no issues.

Comment: Which IC? Part number?

Comment: @LosFrijoles I have been studying about perfect diode or ideal diodes. Thanks for your information. If possible can you provide the IC part number.