# Parallel connection of DC DC Converters with different output to charge the battery

Tags: microcontroller, battery-charging, dc-dc-converter, parallel, capacitor-charging

Generally, in connecting power supplies parallel one can follow current control or droop control rather than voltage control to regulate the output of a dc dc converter. If the output of both the converters are connected together.
As shown in the figure [image: Parallel connection with same output]
Then we can implement those current controlling methods mentioned above.
What if the converters had different output.
The figure shows with different output [image: Parallel connection with different output]
What kind of strategy do we use here current or voltage.

I am thinking that the converter output terminals are not connected together and there is no need to see how much current flows through each converter and voltage controlled mode will be used. Is this correct or wrong?

Mostly the dc dc converter evaluation boards available in the market control their output voltage using potentiometer, resistor trimming, I2C programmable. What kind of strategy should be used to control with Microcontroller using voltage divider, current amplifiers, ADC, PWM generation. There is I2C but the complexity of the coding will be increased. I am not much into coding. For suppose as shown in the figure both the converters are given 36V input and charge the batteries connected to each conveeter output. How can I control the charging here digitally?

Comment: 1) You talk about connecting the outputs of DCDC (buck) converters in parallel, as if that's a completely standard way of doing things. **It is not.** DCDC converters are not designed for that. Not how in your first picture it says "Power module", not DCDC converter. Such a power module will be more complex and **designed to be used in parallel**. 2) Then you suggest using a "buck controller" to charge a battery, be specific what that "buck controller" is, most people would call it a **charge controller**. It can still be based on a buck converter.

Comment: *What kind of strategy should be used...* There is no "should be used", it depends on what the batteries need. Control can be digital or analog as long as the batteries are treated correctly.

Comment: You've asked 11 questions now and received some good answers as far as I can tell. Why haven't you formally accepted any of the good answers? If you want help, you don't want folk to think you are mean or unappreciative of their help do you?

Comment: DC-DC modules and buck converters are not battery chargers. Please do not connect them to batteries or try to charge batteries with them. You need a battery charger.

Comment: @Andyaka. I did not mean in that way I am sorry.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie yes it is a charge controller. Is that possible to connect charge controllers shown in the figure 2 with different batteries at output of charge controllers.

Comment: @Justme thanks for yours anser. Yes I am using battery chargers in parallel to charge the batteries as shown in the figure. But my doubt is that possible to connect them in that way as shown in figure 2. How can I control the output of those charge controllers.

Comment: @KranthiKumarBanala just review your earlier questions and accept the most appropriate answer. That puts things right. No need to apologise. This happens quite often.